# eslint failed to load config "react-app" to extend from

Tags: reactjs, eslint, create-react-app, package.json, autoprefixer

I had a strange issue with eslint before and I had to uninstall node_modules and do npm install and since I did that I have been getting new errors I've never had before within my code. One error that I can't quite figure out how to fix is this.

```
ERROR in [eslint] Failed to load config "react-app" to extend from.
Referenced from: C:\Users\Justi\Downloads\package.json
```

Here's my package.json folder:

```
{
  "name": "gingerrmarket",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.5.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.16",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.0.4",
    "@mui/material": "^5.1.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "firebase": "^9.4.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-feather": "^2.0.9",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

And here's my eslint parser file in babel (I'm not sure if it'll be any use.)

```
   "name": "@babel/eslint-parser",
  "version": "7.18.2",
  "description": "ESLint parser that allows for linting of experimental syntax transformed by Babel",
  "author": "The Babel Team (https://babel.dev/team)",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/babel/babel.git",
    "directory": "eslint/babel-eslint-parser"
  },
  "publishConfig": {
    "access": "public"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/babel/babel/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://babel.dev/",
  "engines": {
    "node": "^10.13.0 || ^12.13.0 || >=14.0.0"
  },
  "main": "./lib/index.cjs",
  "type": "commonjs",
  "exports": {
    ".": "./lib/index.cjs",
    "./experimental-worker": "./lib/experimental-worker.cjs",
    "./package.json": "./package.json"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": ">=7.11.0",
    "eslint": "^7.5.0 || ^8.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint-scope": "^5.1.1",
    "eslint-visitor-keys": "^2.1.0",
    "semver": "^6.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.2",
    "dedent": "^0.7.0",
    "eslint": "^7.27.0",
    "eslint-8": "npm:eslint@^8.0.0"
  }
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? Please help.

Comment: From the code you shared I don't see where it's extending "react-app" at all. Do you have an eslintrc configuration file? Probably named `.eslintrc.js` or `.eslintrc.json`

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/configuring/configuration-files

Comment: @spencer.sm I don't have a .eslintrc.js file or eslintrc.json file but I'd like to extend it in react.json. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running `npm i eslint-config-react-app -D` yet?

Comment: Just did this. Didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

For this all that was needed was

```
"eslintConfig": { "extends": [ "react-app", "react-app/jest" ] },
```

In package.json