# Why am I getting a 'Failed to load config react-app' error when using ESLint with Webpack and vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, webpack, eslint

I use Webpack and Eslint in my project without using React just vanilla JS and I keep getting this problem:

```
ERROR in [eslint] Failed to load config "react-app" to extend from.
Referenced from: C:\Users\Downloads\package.json
```

my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "2048",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack --mode development",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.21.8",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.21.5",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.4",
    "eslint": "^8.2.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.1",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.3",
    "webpack": "^5.83.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.0"
  }
}
```

my WEBPACK:

```
const path = require('path');
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const ESLintPlugin = require('eslint-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
  entry: ['@babel/polyfill', './js/index.js'],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
  },
  plugins: [
    new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
      template: './index.html',
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new ESLintPlugin({
      fix: true,
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

my ESLINT CONFIG:

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true
  },
  "extends": ["airbnb-base", "prettier"],
  "plugins": ["prettier"],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": ["error"]
  }
}
```

Also I use Prettier:

```
{
  "singleQuote": true,
  "printWidth": 120,
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "semi": true
  }
```

The problem was gone when I deleted eslint-webpack-plugin. But I suppose that I need it bc it helps Eslint to work with Webpack

Please help me! And also I'd be happy if you explained to me what eslint plugins I need with Webpack

Comment: Please share your `package.json` since the error seems to originate there

Comment: oh I completely forgot, already added ;)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72924944/eslint-failed-to-load-config-react-app-to-extend-from

Comment: I don't use React

Comment: One of the plugins has a react dependency.